# How to Store and fetch date formate "%m-%d-%Y"

Tags: date, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I want to save my date in `"%m-%d-%Y"` format 
like `User.last.update(created_at: "12/20/2012")` but rails default behaviour for saving data `%Y-%m-%d`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a "real" example from the Active Support en.yml translations YAML file:

```
#config/locales/en.yml
en:
  date:
    formats:
      default: "%Y-%m-%d"
      short: "%b %d"
      long: "%B %d, %Y"
```

you can read more how-to-store-your-custom-translations

This is how I have it set on my own projects

```
    #config/locales/en.yml

    en:
      date:
        formats:
          default: "%d/%m/%Y"
      time:
        formats:
          default: "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"
```

you can try do something like this

```
User.last.update(created_at: Date.strptime("12/20/2012","%m/%d/%Y"))
```

Comment: I have tried my this is not help full for me this is still saving nill value

Comment: you should save in the database `%Y-%m-%d` and then just treat the front end

Comment: User.last.update(created_at: Date.strptime("12/20/2012","%m/%d/%Y"))

Comment: I don't want to do this